# Python source for built-in message types

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can I find Python source code for the built-in message types? I need them for a presentation. I've looked for them but I guess that they are not on GitHub but that they are generated during builds.

Specifically for the moment I am looking for Twist

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302223/python-source-for-built-in-message-types/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message types are generated into the `devel` directory of your workspace (like other things that your source code wants to include), under `devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. The built-in ones are in the install directory, so since you are on kinetic, most likely `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`.

PS: `find . -name std_msgs` helped.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2018-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-03**:
@pitosalas: this is the answer to your question.

If it isn't, then please clarify why you haven't accepted it yet.

All msg packages can be found in the directories that @fvd mentions, including `geometry_msgs`.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-09-03**:
Yes, I found it. I was mistakenly looking in std_msgs. Thanks all!